# Nested Repeaters QML Qt

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

```
Row {
     Rectangle { width: 10; height: 20; color: "red" }
     Repeater {
         model: 10
         Rectangle { width: 20; height: 20; radius: 10; color: "green" }
     }
     Rectangle { width: 10; height: 20; color: "blue" }
 }
```

Here I want the color of each middle rectangle to be selected from a list. i.e. Each color has to be different rather than all being green.

Do I need nested repeaters? How should I go about this?

Comment: When you copy-paste code from somewhere, it'd be polite to link to the source, in this case in [Qt docs](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtquick/qml-qtquick2-repeater.html)

Comment: @hyde I usually do it when code is somewhat big. Okay, will do it from next time for tiny codes also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `index`, as shown below, when model is just a number. And then you need to convert this number into a color, for example using `Qt.rgba()` or `Qt.hsva()` function, as shown below. The first repeater in code (adapted from [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtquick/qml-qtquick2-repeater.html)) will create a sliding *hue* for a rainbow effect.

If you just want to list colors as an array and use repeater to show them, the second repeater shows how to do this. Just set the array as the model, and use `modelData` in the repeater to access the value.

```
Row {
    Rectangle { width: 10; height: 20; color: "red" }

    // use index (values 0..9) to generate "rainbow"
    Repeater {
        model: 10
        Rectangle {
            width: 20; height: 20; radius: 10
            color: Qt.hsla(index/(10-1), 1, 0.5, 1)
        }
    }

    // use modelData to get color string from model
    Repeater {
        model: [ "#808080", "#1100F0", "#F20F20", "#F3F620" ]
        Rectangle {
            width: 20; height: 20; radius: 10
            color: modelData
        }
    }

    Rectangle { width: 10; height: 20; color: "blue" }
}
```

Comment: @TheRebelAquarius YW. I improved the answer a bit, to cover the case of having colors in the model as array, and also changed the first case to use `hsva()`, which is often more convenient than `rgba()` for generating colors from numbers.